# May I convert one of my ill-received, deleted questions to a completely new one in order to try to work towards lifting my question ban?

Tags: discussion, editing, question-answer-ban

I recently have asked a question that received no answers but has gotten a down vote. Since this is my first time to ask after 6 months question ban, my options are limited.
With the down vote and after I deleted it, it counts bad for the question ban, therefore I'm stuck for another 6 months. At least it will be prevented from getting an answer that locks its content in.

Is it ok modify the deleted question to ask a completely new question that will possibly get me out of the question ban?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I welcome your intention to clean up your question(s). Unfortunately that will probably be not as easy. Of your 11 questions only 4 are not deleted, and only one of those is not closed. All these count negatively towards the ban. I am not sure whether fixing one will actually help much (anymore).
You have reinstated the ban yourself by deleting your redemption question less than an hour after posting it.

I also noticed that this was not the first time; most of the deleted questions, you yourself have deleted them, probably within the time frame where this also counts negatively towards the ban. Maybe you have read it already, in case you have not (or want to refresh your knowledge), read the following very carefully: [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/260760)

The questions you are asking are highly speculative, open ended, redundant, or a combination of them. You need to step up your game a lot.

Chameleon questions (if I recall that name correctly) are discouraged, what you wanted to do is exactly that. Why is that so? Because other users have already spent time reviewing your question.
I **personally** would give you that last attempt to fix it *(**@all** if you disagree down-vote this answer)*, but make it fly. (As a hint: If your question title is almost as long as the question body, it probably doesn't show enough effort on your part to be received well.)

You can (and should) try to work on the closed, not deleted, questions, like [this unclear one](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/66265/4945). You have received plenty of help there, yet the question is still in a state where no-one is any wiser.

And since I noticed that also, please familiarise yourself with the chemistry markup we use: [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) and [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/4945). We prefer to not use MathJax in the title field, see [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/149/4945) for details.

I really don't know what to tell you more, it's all been said in one form or the other.

Comment: `The questions you are asking are highly speculative, open ended, redundant, or a combination of them. You need to step up your game a lot`  I agree.  I am happy to have nascent chemists and knowledge seekers here, but the burden of fulfilling the "prereqs" lies in their court.