# What to do if I receive down-votes?

Tags: support, down-votes

The following posts of mine currently have downvotes:

1. [Is Potassium permanganate an oxidizing agent or is the Permanganate ion the oxidizing agent?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/165054/is-potassium-permanganate-an-oxidizing-agent-or-is-the-permanganate-ion-the-oxid)
2. [Convention for writing concentration units](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/165016/convention-for-writing-concentration-units)
3. [How is 1 mole hypochlorite ion equivalent to 1 mole chlorine gas?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/165091/how-is-1-mole-hypochlorite-ion-equivalent-to-1-mole-chlorine-gas)
4. [Should I write formula for oxalate or oxalic acid while balancing a redox reaction using the ion-electron method?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/165072/should-i-write-formula-for-oxalate-or-oxalic-acid-while-balancing-a-redox-reacti)
5. [Why did my book write S2- if hydrogen sulfide isn't ionic?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/165057/why-did-my-book-write-s2-if-hydrogen-sulfide-isnt-ionic)

I have received this message:

[image]

I believe that some of the downvotes I have received are unfair: especially the ones I received in posts 1 and 3. What should be my course of action now?

Comment: Well, first thing is voting isn't all that fair in general, but somehow people rarely complain about loads of upvotes. As far as what can you do, for starters, you can edit old posts, improving them. Otherwise old downvotes are locked. That might worsen situation if they still weren't liked after edit, though.

Comment: Oh, and in this post here you may highlight this question limit thing, perhaps rewrite it with plain text, otherwise people may think it's just another downvote complain.

Comment: So... it doesn't take a genius to see I haven't been around the site much. I didn't vote on any of those posts. But truthfully, I don't entirely understand the downvotes. Obviously, the questions were good enough to get decent answers. Anyway. I think downvotes on *this meta post* are absolutely ludicrous, tbh.

Comment: https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4397/what-is-going-on-with-my-question-ban https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4333/may-i-convert-one-of-my-ill-received-deleted-questions-to-a-completely-new-one https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4190/why-has-my-account-been-restricted

Comment: Sadly, I'm afraid you were hit by "meta effect" - linking questions in meta posts can make things more extreme :(

Comment: @Mithoron .  :-(

Comment: I certainly agree that the downvotes for many if not all of your questions are unmerited.

Comment: @ToddMinehardt I appreciate you saying that :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the issue you're running into is that the anonymity of this site allows individuals who like to "throw stones" to down-vote willy-nilly, purely for their cynical personal entertainment, and independent of whether the question or answer is of good quality.

Thus if you post *anything*, there's a reasonable chance it will be downvoted.  I've listed below a question and some answers I've posted, all of which have been downvoted.  [I'm able to see this because I can view the actual voting history; you may not have access to this—I don't know.]

The difference with mine is that enough people upvoted them to make up for the downvote(s), which didn't occur in your case. So the only solution to avoid going into the negatives is to try making your questions of high enough quality that people will upvote them.

To do this, you'll want to exert significantly more research effort on your own (*compare my question with yours, for instance*).  This can (and should) include finding supporting sources (textbooks and Wikipedia, as well as primary sources), understanding what those sources say, linking/citing those sources, and summarizing what they say in your question.

**Answers**

[Placed in equivalent freezers, would a liter of water or a liter of lava turn from liquid to solid first? (question from a 6 year old)](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141662/placed-in-equivalent-freezers-would-a-liter-of-water-or-a-liter-of-lava-turn-fr/141666#141666)

[What is the cheapest way to give someone 1 mol of gold?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/159215/what-is-the-cheapest-way-to-give-someone-1-mol-of-gold/159226#159226)

[How can a thermometer ever show the actual temperature of an object if the object loses heat to the thermometer?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/134828/how-can-a-thermometer-ever-show-the-actual-temperature-of-an-object-if-the-objec/134840#134840)

**Question**

[Why are IUPAC's definitions of exo- and endothermic disconnected from the direction of heat flow?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/122102/why-are-iupacs-definitions-of-exo-and-endothermic-disconnected-from-the-direct)

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic Well, you can still answer and afaik such ban isn't necessarily permanent. Unfortunately using a different account to circumvent it isn't a good idea.