# What should be done if one "edit a closed question" and write a "completely new question" such that it gets reopened?

Tags: discussion, editing, closed-questions

Assume X is an OP. He writes a question A which gets closed. Now, X has a history of writing poor quality questions. So, he cannot post more questions. He then decides to edit his closed question(A). He removed the question from question body and wrote a completely different question B. X can't wait for this ban to  get removed and in dire need of answers. Two cases arise:

1. B is a poor quality question. Post remain closed.
2. B is comparatively decent. What should be done? Should it be reopened?

For context, see: [Does hydroxy benzaldehyde give test with FeCl3 solution?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/135553/does-hydroxy-benzaldehyde-give-test-with-fecl3-solution). It was [edited](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/posts/135553/revisions) to a completely different question by OP. Now, it has 1 reopen vote.

Comment: [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

Comment: [Similar precedent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299967/if-i-am-permanently-blocked-from-asking-and-answering-questions-and-i-edited-one). I personally don't understand the user whose question is being discussed. They are a member for two years and still make an impression as if they were a new user. Given [the questions history](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/48762/user137644?tab=questions) and the new question posted, I don't see any reason for immediate re-opening.

Comment: @andselisk Forget about him. I am asking in a general sense. If a question is decent (well research is done, body looks like a full fledged question), is it worth reopening?

Comment: If the question has been improved and preserves its original meaning, then sure, in re-opening queue it goes. If the question has been changed completely solely for the purpose of reopening to evade asking ban, then it's a dead end regardless whether the question gets re-opened or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think we as a community should *not* stand in the way of a good question. If that means being a bit lax about chameleon questions, then so be it. I still would prefer that the existing questions are improved in the sense they were originally meant, but I can understand that that is not always possible. The only requirement I would strictly enforce is that they may not have any answers.

That all being said, normal criteria for *good* apply. In general, a question like this will always have a hard time. Usually they come from a negative score, with comments that don't make sense any more. I don't see that the example question is *good*.

I've had discussions with one user about a similar issue. You can find my answer here: [May I convert one of my ill-received, deleted questions to a completely new one in order to try to work towards lifting my question ban?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4333/4945)

In summary:

1. There is nothing to be done. A mediocre or lower question that is closed will go the usual way of closed mediocre questions.
2. Comparatively decent. (a) If it is only decent in comparison with the previous question, it's probably still not *good*. There is nothing we should do (in my opinion). (b) If it is decent in comparison with many questions, I wouldn't object to reopening it. In other words: If you'd up-vote it, it's probably good enough, why not reopen it. Sure, there will be a bit of confusion in the edit history, but who goes through that to get information anyway?