An autoban that's not yet lifted - what can I do? (FIXED)
Thank you all for all of your help in refining the questions I had and reopening a lot of them.
The edits were done to such an extent that I couldn't have seen better versions of those.
I shall hereafter ensure that my questions are quality ones.
I have been lifted from my ban now.

To all the folks out there in ChemSE,
Like everyone knows, I've been banned from asking questions for the past 5 months ever since December '23, and I do admit, I made some silly mistakes like deleting questions with -1 votes or below, which led to the algorithm of Roomba catching me and arresting me.
Ever since that happened I've been adding more and more answers and edits, and from 100 rep I've managed to get to 652 rep, in four months.
I've also been helping in moderation roles by reviewing first timers' Q & A and also help spam clearance with answers to very old posts.
Y'all have told me warmly that you can't do anything, and to use the Chemistry Chat for all my questions. I am afraid, though, that the Chat is not as bustling as the SE itself.
So, I decided to look back at that Mother Meta page...


The crux of the matter -

If you really, really think that the ban is an error, you can contact the team directly and tell them, 'Hey, you've made it wrong!' but no guarantees 'cuz it's not top priority.

What do y'all think about this?
Should I ask for it, because -

I've gained 500+ rep since the ban,
I'm highly active on the site, and
I've got great feedback from ChemSEians about my answers.

What's your opinion Milords?

Ok, you can't undelete the posts. Can you edit any of them at all?

@BuckThorn One can edit own deleted posts. And undelete if deleted himself.

I think you'll just have to wait. And if you want to ask sth, turn existing one into a friggin' good one. I mean undelete one you deleted yourself, that has no answers, and turn it into completely new one - outstanding one. Better yet, let one of us do it. This would be a stretch, but might help. See https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5271/would-this-improve-my-chemistry-question-re-deducing-the-iupac-name-of-lsd-or

BTW I wonder what turning questions into Community Wiki would do...

Coming to my questions - https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/178065/calculation-of-formation-heat-given-molar-heat-capacities-and-reaction-enthalpy is a numerical that I asked, https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/177865/radioactivity-of-promethium is a duplicate on promethium, https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/179309/kekules-description-of-benzene is a question that turned out to be off-topic on ChemSE and had to go to HSM, https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/177936/minimum-possible-molar-mass is a HW question but for which I've shown understanding

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/177894/an-experiment-to-study-colligative-properties - another question in which I required guidance for my school project

Oh, and I've a few deleted answers with scores of -1, but never below that...

@Mithoron my consent is with you. Please go ahead.

If you read the "official policy" you re-posted here you'll see suggestions on how to attempt to undo the ban.  @Mithoron points out this should be possible, which is why I asked why you had not attempted this. Also, what guarantee is there that you will not continue to ask questions that will be poorly received. Upon resuming you will only get one question to start. Read the text you posted again.

There  is a clause that participants should be treated fairly. This means not receiving undue special treatment, particularly from mods. This is taken quite seriously and is the biggest hindrance to - for instance  - my acting on your behalf. However lets see if you accumulate votes here or others provide convincing and upvoted counterarguments in your favor.

@Mithoron please do not revive and edit questions that had a different intent to ask new stuff. This is not considered generally good practice. You are welcome to open edit etc but retain the original intent of a question. Start a meta post if you want to suggest new ideas.

Use the chat rooms. That is by far your best bet right now imho. Use handles (ping) to address mods if you want some attention. Some users visit these rooms regularly. Or perhaps one can be created just for you so you can ask questions there, but then you'll have to invite people into it.

@BuckThorn I understand your position as a mod. Another doubt is that I have written a few of my answers which in the best of my knowledge are correct but I deleted them since they were getting downvotes as I feared being banned.

So you shot yourself in a leg, because result's exactly opposite. Normal course of things for lame questions is getting closed and later deleted by roomba. Or get improved and stay. Your undeleted posts should follow it too.

Okay, I've anyways undeleted all my questions and if they go to salvage by roomba, maybe my account will be cleared of all dues!

I don't know what you mean by "salvage by roomba". There are two aspects to this: there is a bot that decides whether to impose or lift bans. Lifting is based on a timer and/or on changes to the votes on the post, for instance following edits (I don't know what happens in detail behind the curtains). So if the posts get more upvotes the ban may be lifted. You might improve your chances of that by editing the posts.

Roomba deletes questions that are low-quality  (with too many net negative votes) and lacking answers after some time. This has approximately the same effect as your deleting the post  except that you can't undelete a post deleted by roomba so the downvotes are locked in. //Your posts are currently out of view of the front page until you edit them so downvotes are not much of a risk.

@HarikrishnanM Not only you deleted several of your posts, you have deleted and undeleted and deleted the same post. And that has been your downfall. When you do such thing, the algorithm catches up and bans you in asking questions. IIRC, when you ask a question and delete them, a warning message pops up the next time you ask question (I don't remember the exact text, but I remember specifically to be extra careful with my questions).

Moreover, see: https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4333/may-i-convert-one-of-my-ill-received-deleted-questions-to-a-completely-new-one and https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4771/what-should-be-done-if-one-edit-a-closed-question-and-write-a-completely-new

Congratulations on getting your question ban lifted. Please try to be careful with your questions. I appreciate your enthusiasm which is second to none and it always help the community. Welcome back!
